# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Apologies if this is a silly question. 
I searched in stackoverflow. But did not find the solution.
I am working on migration from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8. I am getting the below error for one program.

Please help me.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File " <Path>\main.py", line 17, in <module>
        import script1
      File " <Path>\script1.py", line 9, in <module>
        import script2
      File " <Path>\script2.py", line 10, in <module>
        from googleapiclient import discovery
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

File " <Path>\script1.py", line 9, in <module>  >>> import dfareporting_utils
File " <Path>\script2.py", line 10, in <module> >>> from googleapiclient import discovery
```

Comment: `pip install googleapiclient`...

Comment: Do you have the required package installed? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Comment: just want to know whether code was working with Python 2.7 before you start porting into Python 3.8?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your responses.
I think Python3.8 is not good option.

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

The above one fixed my issue.

I compared Python2.7 & Python3.8 pip list. So I installed version of 2.7 in 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use Python 3.8, please uninstall it and install 3.6.X (X can be 5, my suggestion). The last version of Python 3.8 still can have bugs.

After, please enter this command `pip install googleapiclient` on cmd, or, install `googleapiclient` manual. If you don't know how to do it, inform me, I can edit my answer.